# NotifyBuilder.matches() always times out

Tags: apache-camel

I would like to validate the retry logic built into my Camel route definition.

```
from(somewhere)
.errorHandler(
   defaultErrorHandler()
   .log("something")
   .maxRedeliveries(3)
 )
.to(somewhere-else)
```

To do so I wrote test deliberately raise an exception.

```
int counter = 0;
@Test
public void simulateError() throws Exception {
  NotifyBuilder nb = new NotifyBuilder(mock.getCamelContext()).whenDone(3).create();
  mock.whenAnyExchangedReceived(
    new Processor() {
      @Override
      public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        counter++;
        throw new FooException("Error during processing: " + counter);
      }
    }
  );
  template.sendBody(somewhere, "some message");
  boolean matches = nb.matches(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  assertEquals("Exception raised", 3, counter);
}
```

Now this works fine.  However if I assert on `matches` by adding

```
assertTrue(matches)
```

It fails.  In other words, the `NotifyBuilder`'s match criterion is never met and it always times out.

Why is that?  Is it because **retries** don't count as `exchange` deliveries?

What is the canonical way to test that redelivery is attempted the expected number of times?

Comment: There is only 1 message done, not 3. You can set an expectation that your mock receives 3 messages instead.

Comment: @ClausIbsen That was my suspicion -- that retries don't count as done-messages.  Yes the option is to test that the mock received 3 messages.  However that doesn't really reflect (or prove) that the retry logic kicked in.  I am having trouble verifying retry count like shown here https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/processor/DeadLetterChannelRedeliveryTest.java.  Not sure how to write a mock `onRedelivery` handler as shown there without writing an all new `RouteBuilder`.

Comment: Why would it not, dont you set that the redelivery count was 3, and the counter is 3, and you can set an expectation on the mock to receive 3 messages (maybe 4 as 1 first call and 3 redeliveries)

Comment: @ClausIbsen Alright.  I'll try that.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Closing the loop & answering my own question.

Firstly - Indeed retries don't count towards *done*-messages.

As noted by Claus Ibsen, the preferred (shortest?) solution is to verify that the mock receives the expected number of messages.  That will be `max_retries + 1` (4 in my case).  So the working code looks like

```
@Test
public void simulateError() throws Exception {
    /*
     * Verify the error handling logic by checking the number of messages that are delivered.
     * It must be 1 + number of retries.
     */
    mock.expectedMessageCount(maxRetries + 1);
    mock.setAssertPeriod(6000); // Necessary to ensure the message count is treated as an exact number.
    mock.whenAnyExchangeReceived(new Processor() {

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Intercepted to-endpoint");
            ProcessingFailedException e = new FooException("Error during processing");
            exchange.setException(e);

            throw e;
        }
    });
    producerTemplate.sendBody(umbFrom, "Hello world");
    mock.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```